# SFTP file created trigger in AWS cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, aws-lambda, sftp, amazon-cloudwatch

I have to read and process a file in an AWS Lambda function from an SFTP server that is not on AWS.

Some external source is putting the file in the SFTP server which is not in AWS, and whenever the file is uploaded completely, we have to check it via AWS CloudWatch and then trigger an AWS Lambda for processing this file.

Is this approach right? Is this even possible?

If this is possible, please suggest some steps. I checked in AWS CloudWatch but I was not able to found any trigger which checks the file outside the AWS.

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the external source script ?
If yes, you can send a SNS notification to specific topic using the aws cli or a specific language sdk.
Then you can have a lambda to process your file, triggered by the SNS topic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some sort of job that will monitor your SFTP directory (e.g., using [inotify](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki#info)) and then invoke your AWS Lambda function by using AWS access keys of an IAM user created with programmatic access enabled and sufficient permissions to invoke that AWS Lambda function.

You can also create an AWS CloudWatch event that will be triggered on scheduled basis like every 5 mins that will trigger the AWS Lambda function to check for any news file by maintaining a history somewhere for example on AWS DynamoDB but I would rather trigger the AWS Lambda from SFTP server as using AWS based file-upload on SFTP detection sounds better if AWS Transfer for SFTP is used instead of on-premises SFTP server because it uses AWS S3 as an SFTP store and AWS S3 as the feature of creating an event on files/objects upload and trigger an AWS Lambda function.